# how to search through plugin in wordpress cimy-user-extra-fields?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php, mysql, dropdown

I have a plugin clalled - [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/).

I need to search the content through this plugin. This plugin is in WordPress, and all the content are stored in the database also, like industry, keyword, experience, location. I need to search all the content through the database MySQL. Is it possible to search. What is the code to write in this plugin. Is there any other plugin is there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to used Cimy_User_Extra_Fields plugin for search?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60960/how-to-used-cimy-user-extra-fields-plugin-for-search)

Comment: I closed the other question because this one has an (attempt to) answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to acheive ... but [CIMY extra user fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) is a good plugin and using any sql editor (like SQLyog or PHPMyAdmin) you can browse your WordPress database tables.

You'll see that CIMY creates and stores all this information in the WordPress database. You can find a lot of [helpful material on the plugin homepage](http://www.marcocimmino.net/cimy-wordpress-plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/faq-and-comments/)

To [retrieve the information stored in the database you will need to use $WPDB](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) function